# c++ embedded database to store numeric data coming from stl vectors and retrieved through stl vectors?

Tags: in-memory-database, embedded-database

i'm looking if there is any database with c++ interface in order to store and receive numeric data (int,unsigned int, doubles,floats etc) but also strings.
My application usually contains data in the form of stl vectors so that is going to be the input to the database and like to retrieve data in the form of stl vectors if possible.
I'm looking for an embedded database so that the storage will be in memory with a c++ interface.

I've checked sqlite3 however if i'm not missing something the queries are in the form of sql statements as char** and data retrieved are again of type char**.

I dont have an issue to create a layer on top of an existing interface , however i would like to avoid the conversion of strings to the appropriate c++ data type and also the parsing of the results that again is coming through a long string (char **).

Answer (score 0):

I work at McObject, vendor of eXtremeDB, which might be your solution. It has a native (nonSQL) API for C++ (SQL is optional) and supports vectors of basic numeric data types, strings, and structures.